# XNA - Any Good Tutorials on 3D?

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, xna

Are there any good XNA 3D and 3D animation tutorials? If so please post a link for me. Thanks.

Since someone pointed out how it's vague and will give a lot of possible useless answers, I'll expand on it... Does anyone have knowledge of any video tutorials on how to use 3D textures in XNA and how to animate them. For example a 3D texture of a person with an animation of walking.

Comment: Have you tried, I dunno, Google? Any effort anywhere? Please post what you've looked at and what you consider "good" or you're going to get a bunch of hopefully-not-useless-to-you answers.

Comment: Thanks for the sarcasm, really helpful. I have tried Youtube since I would like video tutorials but I cannot find any good ones on there since most on there are 2D XNA games. "Good" means it explains how to use 3D Textures and how to animate them when specific things happen, like say walking.

Comment: "Thanks for the sarcasm, really helpful." You see the irony here. You'd probably benefit from updating your question to include your preference for video tutorials and other things you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Since I have updated my question, all I have gained is -1 vote and a loss of 2 reputation. And there was no irony, I was being sarcastic to prove that it's counterproductive, and the rest of your post was helpful and I will hopefully benefit from the rest of your post, but not from your sarcasm.

Comment: -1: for using "texture" instead of "model". Reading some basic tutorials (i.e. suggested by Reed Copsey, +1) would have allowed you to use correct terms (and know what to search for). Your update to the question did not really make it any more concrete than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are step by step tutorials on the [Xbox Live Indie Games' Education page](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment).  Many of the [samples](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=4&devarea=16&platform=0&sort=1) include 3D and 3D Animation.